# How do I add lines to a key and different lines as values?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I start put with a file that lists title, actor, title, actor, etc.

```
    12 Years a Slave
    Topsy Chapman
    12 Years a Slave
    Devin Maurice Evans
    12 Years a Slave
    Brad Pitt
    12 Years a Slave
    Jay Huguley
    12 Years a Slave
    Devyn A. Tyler
    12 Years a Slave
    Willo Jean-Baptiste
    American Hustle
    Christian Bale
    American Hustle
    Bradley Cooper
    American Hustle
    Amy Adams
    American Hustle
    Jeremy Renner
    American Hustle
    Jennifer Lawrence
```

I need to make a dictionary that looks like what's below and lists all actors in the movie

```
    {'Movie Title': ['All actors'], 'Movie Title': ['All Actors]}
```

So far I only have this

```
d = {}

with open(file), 'r') as f:
    for key in f:
        d[key.strip()] = next(f).split()

print(d)
```

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The output you show isn't valid python, but `{'Movie Title': ['Actor', 'Actor']}` is a dict where each value is a list. You check whether the movie is already in the dict (and a add movie plus list if not) then append to that list.

Comment: Why do you want each actor in a separate list, instead of `['Actor1', 'Actor2', ...]`?

Comment: `defaultdict()` or `dict.setdefault()` will be useful for automatically initializing each title to an empty list the first time you encounter it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `defaultdict` is usually a better choice:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)

with open("filename.txt", 'r') as f:
    stripped = map(str.strip, f)
    for movie, actor in zip(stripped, stripped):
        data[movie].append(actor)

print(data)
```

Comment: Always love the "pass `zip` the same iterator multiple times" idiom, but you might want to explain a bit more about what that is doing. It's distinctly non-obvious to folks who haven't fully internalized: 1) That itera*tor*s are distinct from itera*ble*s and 2) That file-like objects are itera*tor*s in the first place (admittedly, the OP probably understands #2, since they were mixing a loop over the iterator with manual calls to `next` on the iterator).

Comment: Also, a note for the OP: If you can rely on Python 3.10+, using `for movie, actor in zip(stripped, stripped, strict=True):` will make this more fully equivalent to what you were trying to do (your code would raise `StopIteration` if the file has an odd number of lines, with `strict=True` it will raise `ValueError`, without `strict=True`, it will silently ignore the final line).

Answer (score 0):

So you need to switch between reading the title and reading the actor from the input data. You also need to store the title, so you can use it in the actor line.

You can use the setting of the title for switching between reading the title and reading the actor.

Some key checking and you have working logic.

```py
# pretty printer to make the output nice
from pprint import pprint


data = """    12 Years a Slave
    Topsy Chapman
    12 Years a Slave
    Devin Maurice Evans
    12 Years a Slave
    Brad Pitt
    12 Years a Slave
    Jay Huguley
    12 Years a Slave
    Devyn A. Tyler
    12 Years a Slave
    Willo Jean-Baptiste
    American Hustle
    Christian Bale
    American Hustle
    Bradley Cooper
    American Hustle
    Amy Adams
    American Hustle
    Jeremy Renner
    American Hustle
    Jennifer Lawrence"""


result = {}
title = None
for line in data.splitlines():
    # clean here once
    line = line.strip()
    if not title:
        # store the title
        title = line
    else:
        # check if title already exists
        if title in result:
            # if yes, append actor
            result[title].append(line)
        else:
            # if no, create it with new list for actors
            # and of course, add the current line as actor
            result[title] = [line]
        # reset title to None
        title = None

pprint(result)
```

**output**

```py
{'12 Years a Slave': ['Topsy Chapman',
                      'Devin Maurice Evans',
                      'Brad Pitt',
                      'Jay Huguley',
                      'Devyn A. Tyler',
                      'Willo Jean-Baptiste'],
 'American Hustle': ['Christian Bale',
                     'Bradley Cooper',
                     'Amy Adams',
                     'Jeremy Renner',
                     'Jennifer Lawrence']}
```

---

**EDIT**

when reading from a file, you need to do it slightly different.

```py
from pprint import pprint

result = {}
title = None
with open("somefile.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile.read().splitlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if not title:
            title = line
        else:
            if title in result:
                result[title].append(line)
            else:
                result[title] = [line]
            title = None


pprint(result)
```

Comment: When I try to use this it returns AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines'. ANy idea how to fix this?

Comment: you'll need to change the logic for reading the file a bit, see my edit